# Procedural Wood Blender Internal 2.77a

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine

Is there a way to create a nice procedural wood in Blender Internal?

Tried following this tutorial, but doesn't work with latest version of Blender.

[Procedural wood tutorial (outdated)](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Tutorials/Textures/Wood)

Another great example here.  Looks great, want to achieve this look.  But link is broken

[BA Forum wood (outdated)](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?296800-Free-Procedural-wood-with-Cycles-Blend-file-attached&highlight=rotate%2520procedural)

Found many tutorials in Cycles, but has to be in Blender Internal for export to .HTML

Thanks